# Columns repeats (total number of ID) time within multiple while loop in php

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, mysqli

I create a table in which I create just one `<tr>` and 11 `<td>`. The values of first 9 `<td>` come from one while loop and last 2 values of `<td>` come from second while loop.

Both `While` loops are executing in `<tr>`. Now, I get the correct values, but it repeats the `<td>` as the total number of records e.g I have total 5 records, it gives me 25 records and the first record executes 5 times continuously and rest like that.

My question is to execute the record once, not to repeat the duplicate records.

This is my code:

```
<table id="myTable" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Reg on</th>
            <th>Upload</th>
            <th>Total Upload</th>
            <th>Sale</th>
            <th>Total Sale</th>
            <th>Purchase</th>
            <th>Total Purchase</th>     
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>         
    <?php
    include("connection.php");

    $query ="SELECT s.*, s.student_id, s.student_email, u.student_email, b.payer_email,
        COUNT(u.student_email) AS 'uploadCount',
        SUM(u.price) AS 'uploadTotal',

        COUNT(b.payer_email) AS 'buyCount',
        SUM(b.payment_amount) AS 'buyTotal'

        FROM students s

        LEFT JOIN academic_work u ON u.student_email = s.student_email
        LEFT JOIN orders b ON b.payer_email = s.student_email

        GROUP BY s.student_id
        ORDER BY s.student_id DESC
    ";

    $run = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die(mysqli_error($con));
    ?>
    <tr>    
    <?php
    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($run)) {
        $student_id=$row['0'];
        $student_first_name=$row[1];
        $student_last_name=$row[2];
        $student_email=$row[3];
        $student_password=$row[4];
        $student_status=$row[5];
        $student_time=$row[6];
        $uploadCount = $row['uploadCount'];
        $buyCount = $row['buyCount'];
        $uploadTotal = $row['uploadTotal'];
        $buyTotal = $row['buyTotal'];   

        $query1 ="SELECT ss.*, ss.student_id, ss.student_email, p.email,
            COUNT(p.email) AS 'purchaseCount',
            SUM(p.payment_amount) AS 'purchaseTotal'

            FROM students ss

            LEFT JOIN orders p ON p.email = ss.student_email

            GROUP BY ss.student_id
        ";

        $run1 = mysqli_query($con, $query1) or die(mysqli_error($con));

        while ($row1=mysqli_fetch_array($run1)) {
            $purchaseCount = $row1['purchaseCount'];
            $purchaseTotal = $row1['purchaseTotal'];
            ?>
                <td><?php echo $student_first_name; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $student_last_name; ?></td>
                <td><a href="academic_work_add.php?add_academic_work=<?php echo $student_id; ?>" style="text-decoration:none;"><?php echo $student_email; ?></a></td>
                <td><?php echo $student_status; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $student_time; ?></td>
                <td><?php if($uploadCount == 0) { echo 0; } else { echo $uploadCount; }?></td>
                <td><?php if($uploadTotal == 0) { echo 0; } else { echo $uploadTotal; }?></td>
                <td><?php if($buyCount == 0) { echo 0; } else { echo $buyCount; }?></td>
                <td><?php if($buyTotal == 0) { echo 0; } else { echo $buyTotal; }?></td>

                <td><?php if($purchaseCount == 0) { echo 0; } else { echo $purchaseCount; }?></td>
                <td><?php if($purchaseTotal == 0) { echo 0; } else { echo $purchaseTotal; }?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php
        }
    }
    ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your question doesn't have a question.

Comment: @GordonLinoff .. My Question is to execute the record once, not to repeat it

Comment: @chris85... Thanks it's working... how to upvote for ur answer? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `$query1` loops through all rows of the table on each iteration. Use a `where` clause and then it will return the 1 row you want. Use the id of `$row` to target the correct row. You should parameterize this so you aren't open to a SQL injection (https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/146595/second-order-sql-injection-protection).

This also could probably be done in 1 query, looping a query is usually an incorrect implementation.